# LotusScript to find attachments in all mail files larger than {X} MB

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

As the titles says.

Unfortunately I'm a complete beginner with LotusScript so I have no idea myself.

However we have had for a while no max email attachment size policy in place.. and this has caused us to have lots of people sending 100mb+ files to each other via email.. sometimes multiple times.

I'm wondering if a script is possible that will search all .nsf files in the mail directory for attachments larger than {X} MB. So we can have a report to look through and deal with these files.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a related note: If there's a lot of email attachments, your company is using Notes/Domino 8.5 or newer with fix packs, and hasn't yet enabled DAOS, then they really should enable DAOS in the near future. It can save a lot of server disk space.

Comment: Yeah we're looking at implementing DAOS as we speak :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

You need to learn about the [NotesSession](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html) class and its GetDbDirectory method, the NotesDbDirectory class and it GetFirstDatabase and GetNextDatabase methods, the [NotesDatabase](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS.html) class and its AllDocuments method, the [NotesDocumentCollection](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENTCOLLECTION_CLASS.html) class and its GetFirstDocument and GetNextDocument methods, and the [NotesDocument](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) class. From there you'd ideally want to learn how to deal with attachments, but that's not actually a trival topic. A shortcut approach would be to just look at the NotesDocument.[Size](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SIZE_PROPERTY_DOC.html) property, and use that information instead of actually looking at the attachments.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the heads up of where I need to start :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a LS agent like this if you want BUT, depends in which country you are living, it could be forbidden to inspect the mail box files in this manner  (privacy issues)

Comment: Just publish it here and everyone can decide to use it or not.

Comment: We are in the UK, and are the IT administrators of the company with full control of the system.